# Loop through JSON and retrieve sets when key exists

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have the following data:

```
{
   "storageSummary": "testvalue",
   "audit1": {
         "auditScore": 1,
         "suspensionScore": 1,
         "password" : "value1",
         "onlineScore": 0.99743587,
         "satelliteName": "us2.storj.io:7777"
      },
   "audit2": {
         "auditScore": 1,
         "suspensionScore": 1,
         "password" : "valueX",
         "onlineScore": 0.9992917,
         "satelliteName": "saltlake.tardigrade.io:7777"
      },
   "audit3": {
         "auditScore": 1,
         "suspensionScore": 1,
         "password" : "value72",
         "onlineScore": 0.99930555,
         "satelliteName": "ap1.storj.io:7777"
      }
}
```

In bash, I need to go through this data, to update the `password` for all `auditX` objects. I've tried the following:

```
jq ' .[] |select(has("auditScore")) '
```

But I get an error on the first item:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:23): Cannot check whether string has a string key
exit status 5
```

When I remove the first item `"storageSummary": "testvalue"`in my data, I can loop through my objects (but my data has some items without `auditscore` keys).

The final goal is to run this result in a bash `for` loop to update the password (and do more specific task).

Could you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter for objects using `select(type == "object")`, or use its shortcut equivalent `objects`:

```bash
.[] | select(type == "object" and has("auditScore"))
# or
.[] | objects | select(has("auditScore"))
```

This will return a stream of objects having a field named `auditScore`

```json
{
  "auditScore": 1,
  "suspensionScore": 1,
  "password": "value1",
  "onlineScore": 0.99743587,
  "satelliteName": "us2.storj.io:7777"
}
{
  "auditScore": 1,
  "suspensionScore": 1,
  "password": "valueX",
  "onlineScore": 0.9992917,
  "satelliteName": "saltlake.tardigrade.io:7777"
}
{
  "auditScore": 1,
  "suspensionScore": 1,
  "password": "value72",
  "onlineScore": 0.99930555,
  "satelliteName": "ap1.storj.io:7777"
}
```

---

To set a(nother) field based on that stream, wrap the LHS into parens to keep the context:

```bash
(.[] | select(type == "object" and has("auditScore"))).password = "X"
# or
(.[] | objects | select(has("auditScore"))).password = "X"
```

Answer (score 0):

With Ruby:

```
ruby -r json -e '
JSON.parse($<.read).select{|k,v| v.is_a?(Hash) && v.has_key?("auditScore")}.
    each{|k,v| puts "Key: #{k} \nValue: #{v}\n" }
' file
```

Prints:

```
Key: audit1 
Value: {"auditScore"=>1, "suspensionScore"=>1, "password"=>"value1", "onlineScore"=>0.99743587, "satelliteName"=>"us2.storj.io:7777"}
Key: audit2 
Value: {"auditScore"=>1, "suspensionScore"=>1, "password"=>"valueX", "onlineScore"=>0.9992917, "satelliteName"=>"saltlake.tardigrade.io:7777"}
Key: audit3 
Value: {"auditScore"=>1, "suspensionScore"=>1, "password"=>"value72", "onlineScore"=>0.99930555, "satelliteName"=>"ap1.storj.io:7777"}
```

If you want to change the password of each:

```
ruby -r json -e '
puts JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse($<.read).
    each{|k,v| if v.is_a?(Hash) && v.has_key?("auditScore") 
    then
        v["password"]="XXX"
    end
})
' file
```

Prints:

```
{
  "storageSummary": "testvalue",
  "audit1": {
    "auditScore": 1,
    "suspensionScore": 1,
    "password": "XXX",
    "onlineScore": 0.99743587,
    "satelliteName": "us2.storj.io:7777"
  },
  "audit2": {
    "auditScore": 1,
    "suspensionScore": 1,
    "password": "XXX",
    "onlineScore": 0.9992917,
    "satelliteName": "saltlake.tardigrade.io:7777"
  },
  "audit3": {
    "auditScore": 1,
    "suspensionScore": 1,
    "password": "XXX",
    "onlineScore": 0.99930555,
    "satelliteName": "ap1.storj.io:7777"
  }
}
```