# Loop through JSON, retrieve parent value

Tags: json, bash, jq

This is a follow up to [jq : loop through json and retrieve sets when key exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76254127/jq-loop-through-json-and-retrieve-sets-when-key-exists). Here is the dataset:

```
{
   "storageSummary": 6.8624392E13,
   "audit1": {
         "auditScore": 1,
         "suspensionScore": 1,
         "onlineScore": 0.99743587,
         "satelliteName": "us2.storj.io:7777"
      },
   "audit2": {
         "auditScore": 1,
         "suspensionScore": 1,
         "onlineScore": 0.9992917,
         "satelliteName": "saltlake.tardigrade.io:7777"
      },
   "audit3": {
         "auditScore": 1,
         "suspensionScore": 1,
         "onlineScore": 0.99930555,
         "satelliteName": "ap1.storj.io:7777"
      }
}
```

I want to go through it: when the `auditScore` is 1, I need to store the parent object name (like `audit1`), and the `onlineScore`.

For now, I have something like:

```
DS_OBJECT=$(jq -c ' .[]|select(type == "object" and has("auditScore"))' ${DS_SRC_FILE})

for row in ${DS_OBJECT}; do
    _jq() {
     echo "${row}" | jq -r "${1}"
    }
    echo -e "Processing $(_jq '.satelliteName')..."
    echo -e "onlineScore is $(_jq '.onlineScore')
done
```

So, I need to extract the `parent object name` instead of the `satelliteName` in this code.
How can I do that, with bash and jq (I'd prefer to avoid adding Ruby or any other language, as advised in the former topic)?

Comment: `to_entries` will help you get there, e.g. `to_entries[] | select(.value | type == "object" and has("auditScore")).key`.

Comment: What is the "parent object name"? Are you talking about the keys in the parent object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `to_entries` to convert your object to a list of key-value pairs. This list can be filtered and transformed easily.

```
to_entries[]
| select(.value.auditScore == 1)?
| [.value.onlineScore, .key]
| join(" ")
```

I also suggest not starting 1 new `jq` process per loop iteration, but generate the proper output and parse it:

```
jq -r 'to_entries[]
| select(.value.auditScore == 1)?
| [.value.onlineScore, .key]
| join(" ")' | while read onlineScore name; do
    echo -e "Processing $name..."
    echo -e "onlineScore is $onlineScore"
done
```

Or just do everything in jq directly:

```
jq -r 'to_entries[]
| select(.value.auditScore == 1)?
| "Processing \(.key)...\nonlineScore is \(.value.onlineScore)"'
```